# SaveChanges not working EF Core .NET 7 into In memory database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

We have a lot of tests running using an EF Core in memory database using .NET Core 3.1

These work perfectly

Now we have updated to .NET 7 and Ef Core 7.3 and have a major issue where the database changes being made are not being saved to the context

```
public async SaveEntity(EntityModel entity) 
{
    await DbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The code above does not save the entity to the context

There are no exceptions so I have nothing to go on at all

I know its not recommended to use the In Memory database but thats what we have in place

I was looking at using the SQL Lite in memory mode but that seems to have a requirement for all the tables to exist which will be a total nightmare to setup for every single test and Im not sure where to start?

Has anyone ever come across this?

Paul

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: I have a problem with SaveChangesInterceptor which is not triggered.